# Problem when implementing DFS for a graph

Tags: c++, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I implemented the structure of the graph in the programming language c++, which contains the number of nodes, a array of strings in which the information contents are placed, as well as the adjacency matrix.

```
typedef struct Graph
{
   int n;
   string nodes[MAX];
   double ms[MAX][MAX]; 
}GRAPH;
```

I want to make an algorithm for DFS graph traversal, I made it but there is an error.

```
void dfs(GRAPH* g)
{
    int visit[MAX] = {};
    void dfs_visit(int u) //Here is error: Expected ;
    {
        int v;
        cout << g->nodes[u];
        visit[u] = 1;
        for (v = 0; v < g->n; v++)
        {
            if (g->ms[u][v] && !visit[v])
            dfs_visit(v);
        }
        dfs_visit(0);
     }
 }
```

In the programming language `c++` gives me an error that I need `;` function code `dfs_visit`? Can someone help me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot declare a new function in the middle of another function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which node you want to start searching from.

Here is the general plan for a recursive graph searching code

*main function*

- Construct the graph
- Select a starting node
- Call the recursive function, passing in the starting node

*recursive function*

- mark node passed in as visited
- loop over adjacent nodes

  - if node not visited

    - call recursive function, passing in node